# Redirect all traffic internal ip to interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a 3 docker containers with postfix service. My box have 4 ips (eth0, eth0:1, eth0:2, eth0:3)

**My container info:**

docker run -h mailserverX.DOMAIN.tdl -d -p IPfromEth0:1:80:80 debian:8 /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"

---

**I want redirect traffic like below:**

Send emails through eth0:1 instead of eth0 for container A with ip 172.17.0.2

Send emails through eth0:2 instead of eth0 for container B with ip 172.17.0.3

Send emails through eth0:3 instead of eth0 for container C with ip 172.17.0.4

It's possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible but you would have to be more specific. What kind of containers are you using?

Comment: Added docker command run command line. Thanks